# Error when trying to do multiple joins in tableau

Tags: mongodb, sockets, odbc, tableau-api, simba

I am trying to build a report in tableau desktop 9.3.2 with mongodb (live connection). I using the simba odbc driver for mongodb.  I trying to join  tables but I keep getting errors if I perform more than one joins and also I cannot do anything other than an inner join. It gives the following errors:

> [Simba][MongoDBODBC] (110) Error from MongoDB Client: Failed to read 4 bytes from socket within 300000 milliseconds. (Error Code: 4)
>   [Simba][MongoDBODBC] (110) Error from MongoDB Client: Corrupt or malicious reply received. (Error Code: 14).

It is not even taking 5 minutes, it gives the error immediately. I was working with some sample data(around 1000 documents) and it worked fine. But now I have 800MB of data. Is it too much data?
Also When I create data source filters and do update now it give me an error:

> [Simba][MongoDBODBC] (110) Error from MongoDB Client: Failed to read 262250 bytes from socket within 300000 milliseconds. (Error Code: 4)

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can resolve it?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  We've seen this issue with MongoDB 3.2, which the current version of the driver does not support. This is something we are working on and plan to release in the immediate future. If you'd like to contact Simba directly at solutions at simba.com, we can let you know when this is released and possibly give you a beta version to try out. If you're not using MongoDB 3.2, can you provide more information on your setup?

Comment: Yes I am currently using MongoDB 3.2.6.

Comment: We're aware of this issue and are working on it. Have you contacted Simba yet? If you do, we can loop you in and work more closely with you, and if you're willing perhaps provide a beta build for you to try.